# Question regarding rolling resistance in train motion

Tags: forces, kinematics

Hello I need to write a train model but there is one concept that is not really clear for me...

In the train model we have some forces: Tractive effort, braking effort, resistance to motion and external forces as well. So it seems that for each situation applied forces are different.

If the train is being accelerated it will have tractive effort, resistance to motion and external forces

If the train is coasting it will have only resistance to motion and external forces.

Lastly, if the train is braking it will have only braking effort and external forces.

My question is why in the braking scenario it won't have resistance to motion even if aerodynamic drag and rolling resistance are present? Shouldn't it be considered as well in the braking scenario?

Best regards!

Comment: You didn't define what you mean by "resistance to motion" forces. If you mean aerodynamic drag and friction and rolling resistance then, yes, those are present during braking, too.

Comment: Yes by resistance to motion I mean rolling resistance and aerodynamic drag force could you explain please why are they considered. So in the braking scenario should I consider resistance to motion and braking force as the forces go against the movement?

Comment: Yes, as long as the train is moving - whether it is accelerating, coasting, or braking - forces like aerodynamic drag and rolling resistance will be present. The only time those go away is when the train stops.